# "systemctl status apache2.service" error in starting apache2

Tags: apache2, restart, systemctl

**root@kudo2:~#** sudo systemctl restart apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**root@kudo2:~#** systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server

Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-10-03 14:22:01 UTC; 3min 33s ago

Process: 17190 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 apachectl[17190]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 apachectl[17190]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 apachectl[17190]: no listening sockets available, shutting down

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 apachectl[17190]: AH00015: Unable to open logs

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 apachectl[17190]: Action 'start' failed.

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 apachectl[17190]: The Apache error log may have more information.

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.

Oct 03 14:22:01 kudo2 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@kudo2:~#

Answer (score 2):

Something else is already using port 80. Try starting apache on a different port or else find out what else is using port 80 and move/kill it.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me

Answer (score 2):

You could run `ss -tlnp|grep -w 80` as a superuser to see which proccess is listening on port 80. This process could be configured to listen on another port. This would free port 80 and allow apache to run.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me

Comment: What was the resolution?